# counting self referencing many to many field

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have the following self referencing model that gives who this profile supports.

```
    supports = models.ManyToManyField('self', blank=True, symmetrical=False,
                                  related_name='supporters')
```

And I want the count not supports, supporters that support this user.

Any ideas ?

```
def get_queryset(self):
    qs = super(ProfileListView, self).get_queryset()
    if self.request.GET.get('s'):
        sorting = self.request.GET.get('s')
        if sorting == 'pop':

            qs = ......
    return qs
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Annotate number of supporters like below, solved my problem

```
 qs = qs.annotate(number_of_supporters=Count('supporters'))
 qs = qs.order_by('-number_of_supporters')
```

Answer (score 0):

I will assume I have an instance of your model with the name myUser:

```
supporters = myUser.supports_set.all()
```